# Grant access to views in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a view called testview in postgresql.

I created a new user called testuser.

I would like testuser to have all privileges on all tables and views in the database.

To do this I ran the following commands:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE testdb TO testuser;

GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO testuser;

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO testuser;
```

testuser now has access to all tables in the database, but if I try to run SELECT * FROM testview I get the following error: permission denied for relation testview.

What is wrong? How do testuser get access to testview?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I agree it should work. With permissions `GRANT ... ON ALL TABLES` should include views too.

Did you create the view *after* granting the privileges to `testuser`? If so then it doesn't have the same privileges as the other tables. That's because `GRANT ... ON ALL TABLES` means "on all tables that currently exist". To include tables/views you create in the future, you can say:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO testuser;
```

Or if you want to give more than `SELECT`, you can say `ALL PRIVILEGES` instead.

I think this behavior of `ON ALL TABLES` is one of the most misunderstood bits about Postgres permissions, and it isn't really called out in the standard documentation, so I tried to emphasize it in my own [Postgres permissions overview](https://illuminatedcomputing.com/posts/2017/03/postgres-permissions/).

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this, it should be reported as a bug, or at least documented properly.

Comment: Even years later, this answer is bookmarked for me. Appreciate the clarity here!

Comment: this save me in 2024

Answer (score 12):

```
postgres=# GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE testdb TO testuser;
postgres=# GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO testuser;
```

GRANT USAGE on schema:

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA schema_name TO username;
```

Grant SELECT for a specific table:

```
GRANT SELECT ON tbl_loans_new TO oloffm;
```

Grant SELECT for multiple tables:

```
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA schema_name TO username;
```

Comment: Hi Gerard. I've changed the formatting to show it as code, but it's unclear if everything should be code so it'd be helpful if you went through and updated your answer with appropriate formatting. There's a [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) you can use. Thanks.